# how to get data from json to nodejs and send back to angular application

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, angularjs

I have to take data from a json file to nodejs web-server.js. the data is like a firstname and lastname
and i have to send those data as it is back to angular application.

Comment: You should post specific problems you're having. What have you tried, and if possible include examples. Not only can people not help you with what you've provided, but it looks like you just want people to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This should be as simple as injecting the $http service wherever you are needing it (ought to be a service) and then making the ajax call:

```
app.service('myService', function($http) {
  $http.get('path/to/server/that/returns/the/json')
    .then(function(json) {
      //use the json
    });
});
```

You'll need to set up the service to get that data and return it how and when you need, but that is how you would get information to your angular app from the server.  This is a very basic operation. You need to study the angular docs. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

You'll also want to learn about and use promises when doing ajax operations, both for efficiency and good code structure and readability.